Install Netcdf on Windows
I am posting this question because after spending hours on it I don't know anymore what to try. I basically have no background in Netcdf nor Fortran but for work purpose I have to follow these instructions to install and use a model: Instructions given by the model developers, I need to follow in order to use it
I downloaded netcdf thanks to this link : https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/current/winbin.html
I also downloaded the fortran libraries.
I checked that I had the right path given in Envrionment Variable for Lib, include and path Environment variable :
This is for Path variable but i also did it for include and lib variable
I also installed gfortran as required.
Whatever I do, I just can't make the nc-config --all run properly even if netcdf is installed (I verified it using ncdump command) : Terminal with different command tested
I precise that I would like to use this model thanks to gfortran in order to compile and run it. I am using Visual Studio Code (I don't know if it is relevant to precise it) and I will run it thanks to Python scripts.
I don't really know what to do after that so if by any chance someone has an idea it would be perfect, otherwise if it is really not possible, I will install a Linux boot in order to avoid Windows problems.
Thank you in advance for the help !

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You probably do not need nc-config utility to use netcdf libraries on Windows. The instructions that you are following were designed to be run on Linux or MacOS. You can also try to install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on your machine, or do your development in a virtual machine.

Welcome, I highly suggest to take the [tour]. It is also good to read [ask]. Try to limit the amount of information you put into screenshots. Error messages and terminal output should typically be copied as text into the question itself. This enables others with a similar problem to search for the error.

As stated above, you are using Windows yet are trying to use Linux commands to install something. You will have to explain whether you are using the Windows subsystem. Otherwise what you are trying to do simply won't work

Thank you all for your answers, I'm sorry if the amount of information was not relevant, I tried to put as much as possible in order to give you everything you could need to help me. And good to know for the error as title. I am just using a normal Windows system and tried to follow the instructions but indeed, I didn't notice that it was linux commands.

@DimaChubarov Thank you for your help, I made it work thanks to a WSL, it changed everything ! Thank you for your advice !

Great to hear that you got around the problem. I’m voting to close this question because the root problem was resolved via a different route, that is without windows-built netcdf binaries.
